# Honeycomb ActionBar Title Shadow

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

How can I add shadow under the title text?

The following xml **doesn't** do the trick.

```
<style name="Theme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="TitleTextStyle" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Large">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/title_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">@color/title_shadow_color</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">1</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing the Dx and Dy values?

Comment: I think this is a bug in android, I can also not get shadows to work on actionbar title styles.

Comment: @sgarman Action bar title shadows work starting with API Level 18 (Android Jelly Bean 4.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a shadow under the title of the (native) ActionBar works starting with API Level 18 (Android Jelly Bean 4.3). Works fine in API Level 19 (Android KitKat 4.4).

[See my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26299042/220039) for XML code and a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

It's there, you just don't see it. You need to displace the shadow using either (or both) `shadowDx` or `shadowDy`

(wow, quite an old question, how come no answers except the totally relevant comment by @James)

Comment: What I want to accomplish it something like a glow, that's why dx and dy are set to 0. What matters only is the radius in my case... but code doesn't work...

Comment: I take it there's no way you have not tried just setting bigger radius?) I.e. the 1-px shadow without displacement could end up under the font itself, or be too small for you to notice. Try something sure-fire, like 20