# Add a shadow on ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to add a shadow under the title of the ActionBar. I have tried putting the attributes

```
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
```

but while textColor is working, the shadow isn't. I am using ActionBarSherlock 3.5 but I think it would not work on native either.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't get this to work either on native or ABS backport. Using the approach mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5754027/236743) works great. For the [android:customNavigationLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#customNavigationLayout) layout you can just supple a single textView with your style applied. This has the drawback of having to set the title programatically in your activity / base activity. This can be done by grabbing the value from [Activity.getTitle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getTitle%28%29), which is what the action bar does if a title is set. Not enough time to look into further!

ps Hi Chris!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried on native, but as Jake mentions, if it doesn't work on native, he wont support it in ABS.

If you really did want to override it, and this would ONLY work on pre 3.2 (or 4.0 with ABS 4.X) Then you can grab the `res/layout/abs__action_bar_title_item.xml` put it in your project and change the:

```
<com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ScrollingTextView
        android:id="@+id/abs__action_bar_title"
        ...
        android:shadowRadius="1"
        ... />
```

Of course I do not recommend this! As it will NOT work on native implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a shadow under the title of the (native) ActionBar works starting with API Level 18 (Android Jelly Bean 4.3). Works fine in API Level 19 (Android KitKat 4.4).

Tested with simulators and native devices starting with API Level 15 (Android Ice Cream Sandwich 4.0.3 - 4.0.4).

```
<!-- Settings activity theme -->
<style name="AppSettingsTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- Set the action bar custom style -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- Action bar style -->
<style name="AppActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppActionBarTitleText</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showTitle</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar title text -->
<style name="AppActionBarTitleText"
    parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white_text</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">@color/text_shadow</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">3</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">3</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">1.5</item>
</style>
```

This is a screenshot from an API 18 emulator:

[image]